# TimeSpan picker in DataGridView that allow more than 24 hours

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timespan

I need a way to create a TimeSpan time picker column, that allow more than 24 hours. Right now, I got a TimePicker which derived from the DateTimePicker, but after 24, it turn back to zero. And I didn't find a way to change it's behaviour.

Please help.

thank you!

Comment: What TimePicker did you get, exactly?  I'm not familiar with a class of that name in the .NET framework.

Comment: I found a way to use a DateTimePicker which is usable as a TimePicker.
If you look closely the DateTimePicker, you can use-it as a TimePicker. I had to find an example on the web to use-it in a DataGridView. but the DateTimePicker only allow you to enter "Time of the day", I want to enter a number of hours, up to a full weeks (7 * 24 = 168 hours).

Comment: Well, you can KIND OF use it as a time of the day picker, yes, but it's absolutely not designed for something like that.  But, if the number of hours is all you're interested in, couldn't you just have a TextBox taking in the number of hours, then use `new TimeSpan(inputHours, 0, 0)`?  If you input 50-odd hours the `TimeSpan` object will simply take care of it from there.

Comment: Yes. That's what i'm doing right now. Put i would prefer a tool that let me use something like two NumericUpDown together to help the user field the data.
Do you know any way I could do it?

Comment: Hey Martin, I went ahead and expanded my answer for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you were thinking in the comments, probably the simplest way to handle this is to have two [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2687k5ae.aspx) controls - one that represents the day, and another that represents the hours.

From there, you will need to add a bit of extra logic.  These spinners don't natively support 'rolling over', so you'll have to code it yourself.  You add these to events, and looking through the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s.aspx), I think you're looking at hooking on to the `Click` event.  Nothing else looks particularly interesting.

Your code will look a little something like this:

```
 private void ctrlUpDownHour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(ctrlUpDownHour.Value >= 24)
    {
        ctrlUpDownDay.Value += 1;
        ctrlUpDownHour.Value -= 24;
    }
 }
```

Might also help if you set the `ctrlUpDownHour.Maximum` property to 24.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, probably the easiest way to handle your situation is to simply make a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).

Simply create a new user control with two `NumericUpDown` controls - get started by creating a new item in your project, and clicking on the 'user control' item - this'll get you started nicely.

You can then visually design the `NumericUpDown` controls however you want.  After that's taken care of, you can go into your code-behind, and have something that looks a little like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         // anything else you want to do here
    }

    public TimeSpan GetSelectedTimeSpan()
    {
       return new TimeSpan((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

You can then place this user control like any other control on any of your other forms.  Then when you need the TimeSpan from it, you'll just capture the control the same as you would any other control and go `userControl1Instance.GetSelectedTimeSpan()`.

Blammo, done.

Comment: Ok... But I would need an exemple to how build that in a DataGridView... I don't know how to build a DataGridViewColumn that contain two control.

Comment: @MartinLabelle: You can create a UserControl which has the two NumericUpDown controls on it. You can then add an instance of your UserControl to the DataGridView.

Comment: The boss change his mind, I'm using a MaskedTextBox instead.
But I accept your answer because it's a good example of my question.
Thanks a lot!